# Can I use a function to capsule a line of code?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it is possible to capsule a line of code with some other code? I think my intentions become clear in the js example. I am also wondering if this is possible in Java.

```
var mainModel = openModel("Model.model");

var tries = 0;
var maxtries = 5;
var success = false;
while(!success) {
    try {
    mainModel.packAndcopyModel();
    success = true;
    } catch(err) {
        log('packing failed, trying again; at try '+tries);
        tries += 1;
        sleep_ms(1000);
    }
    if(tries === maxtries) {
        success = true;
        log('ERROR: packing failed, will continue with next action');
    }
}
```

So packAndcopyModel() will zip the model and then copy it to another location. My problem is, that sometimes fails because windows 7 throws an AccessDenied error due to too much traffic on the hard drive. So it should wait one second and try again.

Now to the question can I transform the code above into:

```
var mainModel = openModel("Model.model");

tryFiveTimes(mainModel.packAndcopyModel())
```

My issue is that this while loop appears often in my code and it makes it very unclean. Another plus of the one function is, that if I decide to handle that error differently I only have to change the code at one function and not everywhere the error is actually happening.

I do not expect from you to write me a function tryFiveTimes() only a hint on how to approach the problem would make me happy.

Comment: It seems wasteful to "repack" the model a bunch of times just because transmission failed.  I would try to put the retry logic inside packandcopymodel.

Comment: Oh yeah xD haven't seen it myself, but than I would of course still need the capsule function around the copy part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the retry packages if available, However implementing a retry class in Java should be straight forward too.

Minimal python example. (Sample code, might need tweaks to work)

```
    class Retry:
      def __init__(self, backoff, max_times, list_of_errors):
        self.backoff = backoff
        self.max_times = max_times
        self.retryable_errors = list_of_errors
        self.wait_time = 0.01

      def retry_on_failure(self, fn, args):
        try:
           fn(**args) # here args is a map
        except Exception as e:
           if (any(self.retryable_errors.map(
                   lambda re: instanceOf(e, re))) and
               self.max_times > 0):
              self.max_times -= 1
              sleep(self.wait_time)
              self.wait_time *= (2^self.backoff)
              self.retry_on_failure(fn, args)


    retryObj = new Retry(**config)
    retryObj.retry_on_failure(mainModel.packAndcopyModel, {})
```